# Avoid duplicate in methods with different type parameters

Tags: java, duplicates, overloading

I have two classes that are autogenerated, these classes have the same arguments and methods, lets call them ClassA and ClassB. I need to convert this autogenerated classes to an internal model, so I have created a convertToInternal(ClassA) and convertToInternal(ClassB) but the mapping process is detected as a duplicated code. This is because ClassA and ClassB are exactly the same, and both need to be mapped to the same internal model. I can change the method name but thats not helping with the duplicated code error.

Since both ClassA and ClassB are autogenerated (and also both required per company rules), I can't modify them.

How can I factorize these methods to avoid duplicated code and without using neither parent classes nor interface?

I'm using java 17.

The detected duplicated methods are:

```
public InternalModel convertToInternal(ClassA obj){
    InternalModel rtn = new InternalModel();
    rtn.setId(obj.getId());
    rtn.setName(obj.getName());
    rtn.setOrg(obj.getOrg());
    ...
    return rtn;
}

public InternalModel convertToInternal(ClassB obj){
    InternalModel rtn = new InternalModel();
    rtn.setId(obj.getId());
    rtn.setName(obj.getName());
    rtn.setOrg(obj.getOrg());
    ...
    return rtn;
}
```

Comment: It depends entirely on how your `duplicate-checker` works. You say `...ClassA and ClassB are exactly the same...` but if they are of different types, then `method overloading` should be totally allowed

Comment: What is it that is complaining about duplicate code?  Surely not the Java compiler -- or at least, that can't be *rejecting* the code shown on such a basis.  It is allowed to have different methods with the same name and different parameter types.

Comment: I wouldn't waste 5 minutes trying to code around this. I'd be putting this back to the company. It is their policies that (a) mandated the duplication and (b) caused the duplication to be detected as an error. There is an internal contradiction here that they need to resolve, and wasting programmer time is not the way to do it.

Comment: If you're going to autogenerate near-identical code, as a labour-saving device, then disable the robot that is complaining about the  concomitant duplication of glue code.  Such tools are meant to help, not force you into complaisant agreement.

Comment: This isn't duplicate code, because `obj` is of different types. That's a bug in your duplicate checker.

Comment: What @user207421 said, but have you tried changing the order you call the setters?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I factorize these methods to avoid duplicated code and without using neither parent classes nor interface?

Since you stipulate that the two classes are not polymorphic and cannot be made so, there is no good way to remove the lexical duplication.  This is because it's *only* lexical, not a semantic duplication.  Notwithstanding that the methods being invoked in the two method bodies have the same names and even the same parameter types, they are different methods because they belong to different, unrelated types.

Unless you can get the duplication checker altogether disabled, which I suspect would be a hard sell, your best alternative would be to leverage some feature of the duplication-checker to disable it for the affected methods or the affected class.  See whether it supports receiving localized instructions via annotations or specially-formatted comments, for example.

If necessary, since the analysis it seems to be purely lexical, you could probably fool it with sufficient lexical changes, such as:

- adding different ordinary comments to the body of each method
- changing the parameter name in one of the methods
- reordering the statements in the method body (to the extent that you can do so without causing breakage)

Comment: It works with just changing paramater name, thanks